# How to Access MVC API which is authorize with IdentityServer4

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, access-token, identityserver4, openid-connect

On Owin middleware Startup class I have added OIDC Authentication where response type is "code id_token". With this middleware I can access my authorized controller. But the problem is, I can't access my API in the same domain with this middleware.

I am using the access_token that i stored in the userClaim. But it is returning the HTML of IdentityServer4 login page.

```
    [Filters.AuthorizeOIDC(Roles = "dukkan.sa")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ViewApiResult()
    {
        var user = User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
        var token = user.FindFirst("access_token").Value;
        var result = await CallApi(token);

        ViewBag.Json = result;
        return View();
    }

    private async Task<string> CallApi(string token)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(token);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:57346/api/SampleApi");
        return json;
    }
```

The examples I got to secure MVC API is with IdentityServer3. They are using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation package to authenticate the client from back channel during the API Access request:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions { Authority = "https://localhost:44319/identity", RequiredScopes = new[] { "sampleApi" } });
```

But IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation is not working with MVC5. I can use IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation in MVC 5. But this is accepting IdentityModel with version bellow 2.0.0.

Need solution for it. IdentityServer4 is not supporting properly for MVC.

Comment: Ever got it working?

Comment: hi, @RuardvanElburg, currently i have converted my MVC webAPI2 to .net Core 2 to authenticate it with IdentityServer4. Later on I'll try it again by making my full project in .net 4.5 in a fresh solution instead of current .net v4.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation with MVC5? Because the server is IdentityServer4?

There is no need for that. IdentityServer3 and IdentityServer4 are build on the same OpenId Connect specifications, meaning that you can use IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation for the client while the server is IdentityServer4.

In fact you can use any piece of code on the client that is build according to the specifications of OpenId Connect. I suggest you give IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation a try.

Comment: Dear Ruard, Thanks for reply.
I tried with IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation. but i got conflict with IdentityModel version. My current IdentityModel is more than 4.0 but IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation accept only v.1 and bellow v.2.
I was trying to implement it by down grading my latest versions. but conflict of version is making the solution difficult.

Comment: I don't understand how your version is 4, are you sure it's the same package? Because the latest version of IdentityModel is 3.10. You may want to remove all the packages you've installed and start with the installation of the IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation package. This should include the correct packages, including IdentityModel 1.13.1. Then add the missing packages. Does this solve the conflicting versions?

Comment: Here are some packages I use for .net 4.5 projects:

<package id="IdentityModel" version="1.13.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: I changed the version as you wrote. I am getting this error
`"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"`

Seriously, they need to update IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.

One other thing, are you using `ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.IdToken` for API resource access? how do you get the access token than? can you share your code?

Comment: Perhaps you need older versions. This may depend on the .net framework version. There are lots of samples here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients